# ページによってheaderの色が変わるようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, twitter-bootstrap, scss

**やりたいこと**
ページを移動した際に、ヘッターの文字の色が変わるようにしたいです（Aのページだと、この色。Bのページだとこの色、みたいな。）

**現状**
以下のようなコードでheaderを書いています。仮にこのbackground -colorをページごとに変えたいときはどのように書けばいいでしょうか？

条件分岐みたいな書き方をするのか、それとも違うクラスを与えたりするのか、よくわかりません。どなたか教えて下さい。

**_header.html.erb**

```
<header> 
   <nav> 
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: #ff9933;"> 
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">xxx</a> 
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navi" aria-controls="bs-navi" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
       </button> 
  
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navi"> 
         <ul class="navbar-nav"> 
           <% if user_signed_in? %> 
             <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <%= link_to "手紙を書く", new_post_path, class: 'nav-link', data: {"turbolinks" => false} %> 
             </li> 
             <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <%= link_to "手紙を読む", notifications_path, class: 'nav-link' %> 
             </li> 
             <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <%= link_to 'アカウント編集', edit_user_registration_path, class: 'nav-link' %> 
             </li> 
             <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <%= link_to "ログアウト", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'nav-link'  %> 
             </li> 
           <% else %> 
             <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <%= link_to "新規登録", new_user_registration_path, class: 'nav-link' %> 
             </li> 
             <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <%= link_to "ログイン", new_user_session_path, class: 'nav-link' %> 
             </li> 
           <% end %> 
         </ul> 
       </div> 
     </nav> 
   </nav> 
 </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のような感じで変更できるかと思います！

参考記事:
[[Rails 4.x] ViewからController名やAction名を参照する方法](https://qiita.com/colorrabbit/items/ef91170d9b5c266ad416)

**_header.html.erb**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: <%= background_color(controller) %>;">
```

**application_heler.rb**

```rb
  def background_color(controller)
    case controller.controller_name
    when 'posts'
      '#ff9933'
    when 'user_sesssions'
      '#ff0000'
    end
  end
```